# Kivymd app crashes on statup even after debugging

Tags: python, android, kivymd

I have been writing a code to make an app that can stream mic input to speaker output it works perfectly on PyCharm or any IDE but as soon as a successful installation happens and you do first start up it crashes, IDK why no solution so far has worked this was my first python app. Can anyone help

I used google colab to run builddozer but its not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

```
import argparse
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy  # Make sure NumPy is loaded before it is used in the callback
assert numpy  # avoid "imported but unused" message (W0611)

def int_or_str(text):
    """Helper function for argument parsing."""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l', '--list-devices', action='store_true',
    help='show list of audio devices and exit')
args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.list_devices:
    print(sd.query_devices())
    parser.exit(0)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[parser])
parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--input-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='input device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-o', '--output-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='output device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--channels', type=int, default=2,
    help='number of channels')
parser.add_argument('--dtype', help='audio data type')
parser.add_argument('--samplerate', type=float, help='sampling rate')
parser.add_argument('--blocksize', type=int, help='block size')
parser.add_argument('--latency', type=float, help='latency in seconds')
args = parser.parse_args(remaining)



class THAGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(THAGrid, self).__init__()
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Press To Start"))

        self.press = Button(text = "Press to Hear")
        self.press.bind(on_press=self.hear)
        self.add_widget(self.press)

    def hear(self, instance, ):

        def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
            if status:
                print(status)
            outdata[:] = indata


        try:
            with sd.Stream(device=(args.input_device, args.output_device),
                       samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize=args.blocksize,
                       dtype=args.dtype, latency=args.latency,
                       channels=args.channels, callback=callback):
                print('#' * 80)
                print('press Return to quit')
                print('#' * 80)
                input()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            parser.exit('')
        except Exception as e:
            parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))

class TheHealingTech(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return THAGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TheHealingTech().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `kivy 2.0.0` and `kivymd==0.104.2`. Install them in plugins trough settings in pycharm. And your `buildozer.spec` should be like this:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.2,pillow,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,argparse,numpy
```

Comment: The problem is still persistent I think using Kivy might be an issue can u tell me how can I make an app of this functionality?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `kivy`. You're doing something wrong if it doesn't work. I updated my answer